# Cannot copy 'filename': The parameter is incorrect

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 11.04. I installed Oracle VM and made a VirtualBox. It's configured as:

- Windows XP
- 30GB
- 1024MB of RAM

I insert a DVD and open it in the Windows XP VM. I have two files, about 1.1GB burned onto the DVD. If I copy/paste the files onto the Windows XP desktop I get an error about halfway through saying:

> Cannot copy 'filename': The parameter is incorrect.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: What are the names of the files?  Could it be that one of them has a name containing one or more characters that aren't permitted in Windows file names?

Answer (score 0):

Halfway - does it mean the first file was copied?
If the names of the files differ only in the casing of the letters, the second will overwrite the first (under windows) where the first might be read-only because it was copied from a DVD.

Other idea: The virtual XP drive has no more free space left?